# How to sort JavaScript object using underscore js?

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

Following is my JavaScript object.

```
{
  "014b9d42":{
    "notification": 0,
    "userName": "adam"
  },
  "02f5b60e": {
    "notification": 3,
    "userName": "jake"
  },
  "1281d8fb": {
    "notification": 1,
    "userName": "eomer"
  },
  "12a2a564": {
    "notification": 0,
    "userName": "bella"
  }
}
```

I want to sort the above object based on value of notification. How can i do it using underscore js?

Comment: There is no order in objects

Comment: You would want to have an array rather then an object. Maybe make your keys of your object another property so you could have an array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @adeneo pointed out, [order in objects is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). You'll need to convert the object to an array, then sort based on the `notification` property.

```
var jsonObj = JSON;

var arr = [];
for (var key in jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var o = jsonObj[key];
    arr.push({ id: key, notification: o.notification, userName: o.userName });
  }
}

arr.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
  return obj1.notification - obj2.notification;
});
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8ef3ha80/).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you gave is not a list. Hence it cannot be sorted. If this was a list then you can use the following code:

```js
var a = [
    {"014b9d42": {
        "notification": 0,
        "userName": "adam"
    }},
    {"02f5b60e": {
        "notification": 3,
        "userName": "jake"
    }},
    {"1281d8fb": {
        "notification": 1,
        "userName": "eomer"
    }},
    {"12a2a564": {
        "notification": 0,
        "userName": "bella"
    }}
];

var sorted = _.sortBy(a, function(item) { 
   var key = [Object.keys(item)[0]];
   return item[key]['notification']; 
});

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```